# Set custom shortcut command not working as expected

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, command-line

I want to set a shortcut to open vscode in the current directory,
I have tried

```
code $(pwd)
```

and

```
alias s1="code $pwd" | s1
```

It is working in the terminal but not as a shortcut command, is there is a way to do it?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by "shortcut command"? Also the "current directory" by which application? On terminal you did it, are you trying to do it from the Files application?

Comment: Shortcuts that can be set in the System Setings are system-wide. They don't see the Files application is open, nor which folder it is in.

Answer (score 0):

Go to System Settings --> Keyboard --> Shortcut --> Custom and click the + in the lower side of the right panel.